# How to replace values in column if the count do not reach certain condition

Tags: r, plyr

I have the following example dataset

```
df1 <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2)
df2 <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2)
df <- data.frame(df1, df2)
```

And I want to replace the value of 2 in each column to `NA` if the count of 2 is less than three (count 2 in df1 is 2 and in df2 is 4). Therefore my expected result is

```
 df1 df2
   1   1
   1   1
   1   1
   1   1
   1   1
   1   1
   0   0
   0   0
   0   0
   0   0
   0   0
   0   2
   0   2
  NA   2
  NA   2
```

I know how to replace the value directly, for example, `df$df1[df$df1 == 2] <- NA`, but I am not sure how to add the condition (i.e count).

Comment: What if you have `c(2,1,1,2,1,2,1,2)`? Should the twos be replaced with `NA`?

Comment: @nicola I am working with genetics data where "2" is the count of minor allele. So usually the count for "2" is very little (less than the other categories).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Base R

```
df1[df1==names(which(table(df1) < 3))] = NA
df2[df2==names(which(table(df2) < 3))] = NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Try working with `data.table`, it is much faster and easier. For your purpose this should do

```
df1 <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2)
df2 <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2)
df <- data.frame(df1,df2)
library(data.table)
dt<- as.data.table(df)
dt[df1==2,df1:=NA]
```

If you want to add a condition you could do something like

```
df1 <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2)
df2 <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,1,2)
df <- data.frame(df1,df2)
library(data.table)
dt<- as.data.table(df)
dt[df1==2,df1:=ifelse(df2==1,NA,df1)]
```

Comment: Don't use ifelse in data.table. It's inefficient.